# How do I get a list of Controller Names in CakePHP to validate user data against?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm building a CakePHP site for a client and I've got a bit of an interesting problem.  They want to add a new feature whereby users can create their own landing pages within the site using this type of URL: `http://mainsite.com/username`.  Since this is a Cake site, there are plenty of values for `username` that would result in all sorts of routing craziness, especially if they happened to pick a username that was the same as a controller within the site.

My approach is something like this: in the `beforeValidate` function of the Users controller, check the supplied username against a list of all of the controller names and return `false` if there's a match.  My question is - how can I get a list of all of the controller names (short of actually looping over the files in `/app/controllers`)?  Is it even possible to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could probably use
CakePHP 1.x

```
$Controllers = Configure::listObjects('controller')
```

CakePHP 2.x

```
$Controllers = App::objects('controller');
```

Comment: Update for future visitors: if you are using CakePHP 2.x, the list can be retrieved as `$Controllers = App::objects('controller');`.

Answer (score 3):

Perfect! The beginnings of my solution:

```
$human_controllers = Configure::listObjects('controller');
$u_controllers = array();
foreach($human_controllers as $c){
    $u_controllers[] = Inflector::underscore($c); // converts "PageContents" to "page_contents"
}
debug($u_controllers); die();
```