# How do I get a list of all functions inside a controller in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I needed to select a controller in [CakePHP 2.4](http://cakephp.org) and display all the functions written in it. I found how to list controllers from this question & answer thread on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/898206/576523) but what I need now is given a specific controller I need to get the list of all functions it contains.

Here what i have done

```
public function getControllerList() {

   $controllerClasses = App::objects('controller');
   pr($controllerClasses);
   foreach($controllerClasses as $controller) { 

      $actions = get_class_methods($controller);
      echo '<br/>';echo '<br/>';
      pr($actions);

   }
}
```

pr($controllerClasses); gives me list of controllers as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => AppController
    [1] => BoardsController
    [2] => TeamsController
    [3] => TypesController
    [4] => UsersController
)
```

however pr($actions); nothing... :(

here you go the final working snippet the way i needed

http://www.cleverweb.nl/cakephp/list-all-controllers-in-cakephp-2/

```
public function getControllerList() {

        $controllerClasses = App::objects('controller');
        foreach ($controllerClasses as $controller) {
            if ($controller != 'AppController') {
                // Load the controller
                App::import('Controller', str_replace('Controller', '', $controller));
                // Load its methods / actions
                $actionMethods = get_class_methods($controller);
                foreach ($actionMethods as $key => $method) {

                    if ($method{0} == '_') {
                        unset($actionMethods[$key]);
                    }
                }
                // Load the ApplicationController (if there is one)
                App::import('Controller', 'AppController');
                $parentActions = get_class_methods('AppController');
                $controllers[$controller] = array_diff($actionMethods, $parentActions);
            }
        }
        return $controllers;
    }
```

Comment: sorry about that little gimme....i will update my code in a few minutes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:
https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-sandbox/blob/master/Plugin/Sandbox/Controller/SandboxAppController.php#L12

It basically uses a very basic PHP function:

```
$actions = get_class_methods($Controller);
```

Then get parent methods:

```
$parentMethods = get_class_methods(get_parent_class($Controller));
```

Finally, using array_diff you get the actual actions in that controller:

```
$actions = array_diff($actions, $parentMethods);
```

Then you can still filter out unwanted actions.