# cakephp - scandir failed to open dir error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, scandir

I'm tryin to get a  list of controller files

```
$files = scandir(APP_DIR . '/Controller/');
```

...but I get this error:

```
Warning (2): scandir(src/Controller/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory [APP/Controller/HomeController.php, line 13]
```

... when i try to remove some file names from the list:
`$files = array_diff( $files, array('.','..','Component','AppController.php','HomeController.php'))`;

... i get this error:

```
Warning (2): array_diff() [function.array-diff]: Argument #1 is not an array [APP/Controller/HomeController.php, line 23]
```

my entire class looks this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use ReflectionClass;
use ReflectionMethod;

class HomeController extends AppController{
    public function index(){

        /**
         * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963786/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-functions-inside-a-controller-in-cakephp
         * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892594/list-all-controllers-actions-in-cakephp-3
         */

        $files = scandir(APP_DIR . '/Controller/');
        $controllers = [];
        $ignoreFilesList = [
            '.',
            '..',
            'Component',
            'AppController.php',
            'HomeController.php'
        ];

        $files = array_diff( $files, array('.','..','Component','AppController.php','HomeController.php'));
        $className = '';
        $class = null;
        $ignoreList2 = ['beforeFilter', 'afterFilter', 'initialize', 'delete'];


        echo is_array ( (array)$files );// returns 0 without cast

        foreach( (array)$files as $file){

                $controller = str_replace('Controller', '', explode('.', $file)[0]);
                array_push($controllers, $controller); //str_replace('Controller', '', $controller));

                //dump( $controller );

                /* controller methods */
                $this->$className = 'App\\Controller\\'.$controller.'Controller';
                $this->$class = new ReflectionClass($this->$className);
                $methods = $this->$class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

                echo "<ul><li>$controller</li>";
                echo "<ol>";

                foreach($methods as $method){

                    if ( isset( $method->name )){

                        if($method->class == $className && !in_array($method->name, $ignoreList2))
                        {
                            $controllers[$controller][]= $method->name;
                            echo "<li>$method->name</li>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo "</ol>";
                echo "</ul>";

        }

        $this->set('allControllers', $controllers );
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're running into a config issue. What is the full path to `HomeController.php`?

Comment: @TonyChiboucas, relative to the other controllers? It's in that same directory as the others. They sit in /src/Controller/ 
Added screenshot of the dir layout

Comment: Why didn't I see this sooner, scandir doesn't play nice with relative paths. Try `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/'. APP_DIR .'/Controller/';  $files = scandir($path);` or some variation thereof. You'll have better results defining a root path for scandir.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas - spot on :-) I'll gladly accept it as an answer.

Comment: The proper path constant to use is `APP`, which contains an asbolute path that points to the `src` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Only use [PHP: scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) with a full path.

While the PHP documentation says nothing about it, ***scandir*** generally does not play nice with relative paths. (Though there are cases where relative paths can work perfectly fine.)

#### Path arg is a relative path here

As `APP_DIR` stores a single directory name, and not a path, scandir will attempt to access `src/Controller/`, which may not relative to the script currently running.

```
$files = scandir(APP_DIR . '/Controller/');
```

#### Solution 1: Use [CakePhp: constant `APP`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#core-definition-constants) to build the full path

Thanks to [ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm) for reminding us of the `APP` constant in his comment on the OP. `APP` stores an absolute path to your application directory, including a trailing slash.

```
$path = APP .'Controller/';
$files = scandir($path);
```

#### Solution 2: Use [PHP: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to build a full path.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/'. APP_DIR .'/Controller/';
$files = scandir($path);
```

Alternatively, you ***may*** be able to use [PHP: Realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to retrieve the full path. **reminder: working directory will vary depending on the script running.*